# como resto un dia? en mysql

Tags: mysql

Necesito  que

```
SELECT Date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

me da el formato fecha siguiente:
ejemplo:

```
    +--------------+
    | fecha actual | 
    +--------------+
    |  2020-11-20  |
    +--------------+
```

Que al restar me salga:

```
    +--------------+
    |     ayer     | 
    +--------------+
    |  2020-11-19  |
    +--------------+
```

Utilize esto:

```
SELECT Date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Están haciendo la misma tarea ??

Answer (score 0):

Propongo utilizar el operador `-` en vez de la función `DATE_SUB()`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando la función `DATE_SUB()`
Ejemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AS yesterday;
```